# Gravitons passing through matter like neutrinos

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, neutrinos

I have read these :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino

where it says:

> The weak force has a very short range, gravity is extremely weak on the subatomic scale, and neutrinos, as leptons, do not participate in the strong interaction. Thus, neutrinos typically pass through normal matter unimpeded and undetected.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/414094/132371

Where it says:

> gravity isn't blocked by anything, so stars are transparent to gravitons.

Question:

1. Do gravitons pass through matter like neutrinos?
2. Do a far away star's gravitational effects reach us even if the star is behind the Sun?

Comment: Which version of beyond-the-Standard-Model physics are you using to define gravitons?

Comment: I was going on Wikipedia and this answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179587/132371

Comment: I quote from that answer: "for the spin two graviton [the higher-order Feynman diagrams] diverge (non re-normalizable) leading to nonsense." The interactions between gravitons and other matter are not well-defined in the Standard Model.

Comment: To quote from an answer further down that page: "Yes, I know gravitons are 'just a theory', but I'm wondering how they theoretically act.

To echo Anna's answer, but putting it more bluntly: they don't."

Comment: yes I read that just did not know what THEY was. Did she mean "gravitons don't theoretically act?"

Comment: She meant that there is no current theory that would make gravitons make sense as a particle (certainly not the Standard Model). There are lots of string theories that have gravitons, but they all say very different things about the graviton, so in order to say anything concrete, you have to arbitrarily pick one.

Comment: Gravitons aside, gravitational shielding effects have never been detected, to within fairly stringent experimental limits, as discussed in the two links in my comment on my answer that you linked above.

Comment: @probably_someone by "lots of string theories" do you mean the five consistent ones? If so, they are related to each other by S- and T-dualities